# How can I add a coupon code and product id to url in opencart 3.x?

Tags: url-parameters, opencart-3

Currently when a customer enters a coupon code, they are sent to the checkout page with a url such as www.example.com/shop/index.php?route=checkout/checkout. How can I add the coupon code and product id to the url so that I can send the link to a customer and they can simply fill out the checkout page with the coupon already applied without going through the product page and cart?

Comment: It sounds like you're generating the orders for the customers? Why not just create a mod (or buy an existing one off the opencart marketplace) to generate a payable invoice (after the order is generated) that can be paid afterwards/later? This way, the customer can just log into their account and pay the order/invoice that you generated or an invoice can be emailed to them with a payment link. There are one or two mods that do this already in the OC marketplace. This just seems like a far simpler approach.

Comment: I did want to generate orders for customers. The thing is account creation is not required in this scenario and I can't create accounts for customers without their permission (also telling them that they have to create an account to make a purchase is a bit of a hurdle). So what I wanted to do was send them a link to the checkout page with the product added and discount already applied.

Comment: You can do what I suggested with guest checkouts, too. Guests do get emails after orders are generated. In this case, you're just needing to implement a link to get that payment within the email that gets sent. It's a simpler approach. There are extensions on the market that already do this if you search for them. However, if you continue to choose to stick to what you are initially describing/requesting, you may want to post code that you have attempted already.